# How can I make it so that in unity when using cinemachine the zooming in can be controlled by the scroll wheel and not the mouse

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I don't know how to make the input and the game I am making is an rpg type game if any context is needed.

I've tried researching and I can't figure it out and I am just very new to c#

```
This is what the camera looks like. [1]: 2.pnghttps://i.stack.imgur.com/rPit2.png
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.